# cannot deploy EJB application in Glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, jms

Due to some server problems we migrated from **Glassfish v2.1** to **Glassfish v3.1**. I deployed a lot of web applications there and all are running fine. But today when I deployed an **EJB** application the following Error comes....

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.LocalStrings, locale en_US
```

And

```
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: No local string defined
```

From internet I found that it is a **bug** in Glassfish 3.1. Here is the link.

[glassfish-15981](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15981?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels)

The link says this bug is fixed in *Glassfish 3.1.1* but I cannot change the server again as it takes a lot of effort to redeploy/configure the applications. Moreover we have don't have SSL certificate with us.

**So could anyone please tell me that is there any other way to solve this in Glassfish 3.1 itself ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: As I see it, you've already identified the viable/correct solution.  Glassfish 3.1.2.X has been out for over a year?  And this just came up yesterday?  Someone messed up!

Comment: Suggest someone take the time & effort to automate glassfish configuration for your production/test/dev environments.. that'll help eliminate other problems going forward as well.